# Help! Overleaf lost all the contents of the main.tex file

Tags: overleaf

I was working on a project and fixing some problems with a .bib file that I copied from another project, when suddenly I only got empty error messages by Overleaf and now the main.tex file is completely empty. I did not have any saved versions of the project yet. I cloned the project via git and the main-file there is empty as well. There is still a downloadable version of the pdf, but the project contained some very complicated tikz-graphs and other things that would kill me if I had to redo them. Is there any hope that I can recover my project?

Comment: Welcome! You need to ask Overleaf this, unless you have a saved version within the project.

Comment: @LianTze I am interested: Does Overleaf do some kind of backup or is this (as with any other software) up to the writer/developer/user?

Comment: Quick update: it turns out that the Pro version (which I just bought now) has a far more extensive versioning tool, so I was able to recover my code at least. I'll post another update if I get feedback from their support team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was fixed in the comments.

Comment: A fix in the comments will likely get the  question deleted, meaning no use to people with the same issue in the future. Can't we have a sort of *definitive* answer here? *knowing that Overleaf staff and support are registered members here on TeX.SX*

Comment: (Can't reply so posting comments)
The 24-hour File History (the clock icon just next to "Edit") can restore a file's history in the last day.

If the edits needed are beyond 24 hours ago, or an entire file was deleted, the Full History feature will be useful:
https://www.overleaf.com/help/286

The Full History is a Pro plan feature; can be accessed by activating a free Pro trial at https://www.overleaf.com/plans if you don't want to subscribe immediately.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes there is; see https://www.overleaf.com/help/286

Comment: @Johannes_B Vote to reopen? We have an authoritative answer in the comments that could be a proper answer. Even though in general I would say questions of this type are off-topic, this might be a nice exception.

Comment: @moewe i voted.

Comment: @LianTzeLim The question has been reopened. If you would like to add an answer that would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @moewe; I've added that comment as an answer with a bit more details (the same info I gave to the OP's message that was sent to Overleaf's support inbox.)

Comment: The Overleaf explanation is crap. I can select the file and can save a zip, but how to replace present version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.com.)*

If you have not [saved a labelled snapshot](https://www.overleaf.com/help/38-can-i-save-versions-of-my-work) in the "History & Versions" menu that you can restore from, there are two other possibilities.

The **24-hour File History** (the clock icon just next to "Edit") can restore a file's history in the last day. Clicking on that icon will display the 24-hour history of the file *currently loaded* in the source code panel. (This is available across all subscription plans, including the Free plan.)

If the edits needed are beyond 24 hours ago, or an entire file was deleted, the **Full History** feature will be useful; see https://www.overleaf.com/help/286 for further details.

In brief: Browse through your project's *Timeline* or *Recent Activities from the* "History & Revisions" tab. If you then see an edit that you need, you can click on the **view source** link (before or after the change) and then on **copy** to copy the entire file contents at that point; or use the **download .zip** to download the entire project before/after that point.

The Full History is a Pro plan feature; it can be accessed by activating a free Pro trial at https://www.overleaf.com/plans if you don't want to subscribe immediately.

Comment: If you upgrade to a Pro plan for Full History, do you get access to past revisions from before you upgraded?

Comment: Is there something equivalent for Overleaf comments? After renaming a .tex file, the first `git push` timed out and the following one deleted & re-created the file. It has therefore still the original contents, but all comments were lost in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is that you check the dashboard, check the "history" and click "restore file" given that there are no or 0 changes in the "main.tex" file,
Good luck.